# Neo4j thinks that password is database

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

I am trying to integrate Spark and Neo4j. I am new to Neo4j. I have the following short Spark app

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import org.neo4j.spark._

object Neo4jStorer {

  var conf :Config = null
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = getSparkSession()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val g = Neo4jGraph.loadGraph(sc, label1="a", relTypes=Seq("rel"), label2 = "b")
    val vCount = g.toString

    println("Count= " + vCount)
  }

  def getSparkSession(): SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("SparkNeo4j")
      .config("spark.neo4j.bolt.url", "neo4j://127.0.0.1:7687")
      .config("spark.neo4j.bolt.user", "neo4j")
      .config("spark.neo4j.bolt.password", "FakePassword")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

I used https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-apache-spark-connector/ as an example for this code as I am using Spark 3.0. When I run this I get the following

```
20/10/17 14:36:36 ERROR LoadBalancer: Failed to update routing table for database 'FakePassword'. Current routing table: Ttl 1602963396190, currentTime 1602963396527, routers AddressSet=[], writers AddressSet=[], readers AddressSet=[], database 'FakePassword'.
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.FatalDiscoveryException: Unable to get a routing table for database 'FakePassword' because this database does not exist
```

If I change the password I get an authentication error and I see that again the incorrect password is shown as being a database. I created a database with the name FakePassword and I still got the same error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Also when I tried to get g.vertices.count as is shown in the example I am following I get a compilation error.

Comment: The neo4j bolt url starts with `bolt://...`. Can you correct it and check? Also since you are trying to run it locally u can specify `.builder().master("local")` to connect URL to your local.

Comment: Changing to bolt and using .builder().master("local") did not work. I found another solution. I included it below. It might not work for everyone who had my problem, and I am open to improvements.

Answer (score 0):

With this code I am able to get data from a DataFrame into Neo4j, which is what I really wanted to do. This does not seem to be the ideal solution as it uses foreach. I am open to improvements.

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.neo4j.driver.{AuthTokens, GraphDatabase, Session}
import org.neo4j.spark._

object StackoverflowAnswer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = getSparkSession()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3)).toDF

    df.foreach(
      row => {
        val query = "CREATE (n:NumLable {num: " + row.get(0).toString +"})"
        Neo4jSess.session.run(query)
        ()
      }
    )

  }

  def getSparkSession(): SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("SparkNeo4j")
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}

object Neo4jSess {
  /**
   * Store a Neo4j session in a object so that it can be used by Spark
   */
  var conf :Config = null

  this.conf = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("DeltaStorer")

  val neo4jUrl: String = "bolt://127.0.0.1:7687"
  val neo4jUser: String = "neo4j"
  val neo4jPassword: String = "FakePassword"

  val driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4jUrl, AuthTokens.basic(neo4jUser, neo4jPassword))

  val session: Session = driver.session()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.jars.packages             neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.4.5-M2
spark.neo4j.url                 bolt://XX.XXX.X.XXX:7687
spark.neo4j.user                neo4j
spark.neo4j.password            test
```